# How can I know how my app was launched on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, service, local

I've got a problem, and have been looking for a solution for a long  time.

I made a application which has an **option** which will launch the app automatically when the system starts using Launch Services.

If application is launched by the user (ie. opening the .app) I want to do something.
If application is launch by Launch Services when the system starts I want to do another thing.

So I need to know how the app was launched: by the System (Launch Services loading the app when the computer turns on) or User (User opening the .app in the Finder).

How can I get this information?
Any suggestions are weclome.

prethanks.

Comment: Between your English and your question, you might hv to give points to everyone who understand you :)

Comment: Thanks for your replay,I will try my best to make it easy to understand.

Comment: I think that this question is very clear and excellent...

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465100/know-if-the-user-launched-an-app Even if it doesn't really help me...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597328/mac-os-x-open-application-at-login-without-showing-the-main-window